# Mathematica windows animation on Linux

Tags: linux

Mathematica 10.4 is being nasty to my tiling window manager (Awesome wm). It works perfectly in GNOME, but it won't open any new windows under Awesome.

On GNOME, every time I open a new window, they appear with this funny transparency animation that I think Awesome can't handle. How can I prevent this animation from happening? I couldn't find anything in the extended preference dialog.

Thanks.

Comment: This problem has been addressed in the development version, I expect the fix will be available in the next release.

Comment: A pic would be appreciated but not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer, the underlying cause is a bug that has been fixed as of version 11.0.0.